# How to select all the value through query in script

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

How to select all the columns using script.,

```
purge_assessment_query="SELECT * FROM WK.BATCH c"
echo $purge_assessment_query
```

Whenever I echo the above query in shell script., it's printing all files that are inside the current directory.  Later it's printing the part the command..

like below

```
Select 1 test.sh test2.sh FROM WK.BATCH c
```

What's wrong in "*".  Please help me resolve this.

Comment: that is not answerinng my need remove dulpicate.

Comment: You set a variable and then echo it without quotes, then ask why it shows files in the current directory. The duplicate question explains why asterisks show files in the current directory and how to fix it. How does it not answer your question?